O(n log n) algorithm to find number of large inversions
I am working on a problem where I need to find the number of large inversions in an array. A pair (i, j) is considered a "large inversion" if i<j and rank[i] > rank[j]+k for some given k, i.e. the inversion pairs are far enough apart from each other in the given array.
For example, if we have [2, 4, 1, 3] and k = 1, we have 2 large inversions because (2, 1) are a distance of 2 away from each other, and (4, 3) are a distance of 2 away from each other. (4, 1) is another inversion but it's only a distance of 1 away from each other so the inversion is not large enough.
I am familiar with the traditional approach of using a modified merge sort to count regular inversions, which works in O(n log n) time. However, I am unsure how to extend this idea to count "large inversions".
Can a merge sort algorithm be extended to find the number of large inversions in O(n log n) time? Or maybe a different approach?
I tried computing all the inversion pairs and filtering out the inversions that are not large enough by comparing indices, but computing all the inversion pairs can only be done in O(n^2) time.

"that are not large enough by comparing the indices": I am confused. Is  the minimal difference between indices or between values? Your earlier formula indicates the latter, but this statement of "comaring the indices" seems to suggest the former.

@trincot Edited and cleared up the confusion by giving an example. k is the minimal difference between indices

If it is the minimal difference between indices, then the formula in the first paragraph is wrong. It should not have arr[j] + k as then you add  to a value, not to an index. I would guess you would need something like j - i >= k. So maybe: "if i+k<=j and rank[i] > rank[j]"

The formula is extremely misleading. Your elements are i and j and your indices are rank[i] and rank[j]. What kind of notation is that?!

You can simply use a binary indexed tree (after coordinate compression) or an order statistic tree to count the number of previous elements greater than the current value while iterating over the array. To handle the condition of a minimum difference in indexes, add elements to the data structure only once they are at least k indexes before the current index (e.g. at the end of the ith iteration of the loop, add arr[i - k] if it exists).

One method is to merge three arrays instead of two at each step of mergesort. Two arrays are the same as in the normal mergesort, and the third array contains all the numbers in the sorted left half increased by k. The third array is used to count the inversions.
Edit: this answers a different version of the question, one where the elements (instead of indices) should differ by at least k.
